# With Excel interop, after I have checked out a file, how do I check it back in?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I use Excel's application interface to connect to Excel:

```
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
excelApp.Workbooks.CheckOut(fileName);
```

but there is no `CheckIn` method. How do I check in a previously checked-out file?

Comment: Interesting. **1.** Is the call to `CheckOut` actually necessary in order to edit the file? `Open` has a whole lot of optional parameters, including one named `ReadOnly`; suggesting that `Open` can be used for write access to a workbook. **2.** Even if the `CheckOut` is necessary, what happens when you simply "save as" the resulting workbook with its original filename?

Comment: checkout is for server location

Comment: The documentation says so, yes. But my questions remain.